# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript

In google chrome Console, the error showing is

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**

```
var description=["a","b","c","d","e"];
var count=1;   
document.getElementById("productdescription").innerHTML = description[count-1];
```

I am calling this function on an onclick event to imagebutton

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Do you have an HTML tag with attribute `id = 'productdescription'`?

Comment: your Html element is Not found. try to debugg or paste whole code here so that bug can be resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake. I declared a `div#showproduct` covering the `div#productdescription` and before calling `div#productdescription` innerHTML attribute, i was calling innerHTML attribute of the `div#showproduct`. so, the `div#productdescription` was being erased.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have an element with the id productdescription (perhaps capitalization), therefore `document.getElementById("productdescription")` is returning null.